# Type string is not assignable to type '"mysql"'

Tags: nestjs

I have two files environemtn.ts where I stored database configs info, I called vars in app.module.ts file but it cannot getting value `Type string is not assignable to type '"mysql"'`

**Following code of environment.ts**

```
const path = require('path');
export const environment = {
  /* Configurations used for TypeORM */
  database_type: 'mysql',
  database_username: 'root',
  database_name: 'database_name',
  database_password:  null,
  database_port: '3306',
  database_prefix: 'prefix_',
  database_host: 'localhost',
  encrypt:true,
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: false,
  logging: true,
};
```

Following code of **app.module.ts** file

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';



@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: environment.database_type,
    host: environment.database_host,
    port: environment.database_port,
    username:  environment.database_username,
    password: environment.database_password,
    database: environment.database_name,
    entities: [],
    synchronize: true,
  })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: what's your typeorm version please?

Comment: You can write it  type: environment.database_type as any,

Answer (score 1):

type option expected a **string literal type** not a **string**: read more about [string literal type](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/string-literal-types-in-typescript#:%7E:text=A%20string%20literal%20type%20is,in%20the%20string%20literal%20type.)

```
import {ConnectionOptions, DatabaseType} from 'typeorm';    
.....
const dataBaseType: DatabaseType = environment.database_type;
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: dataBaseType,
    host: environment.database_host,
    port: environment.database_port,
    username:  environment.database_username,
    password: environment.database_password,
    database: environment.database_name,
    entities: [],
    synchronize: true,
  })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```